# Como imprimir con SQL una hoja personalizada

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Alguien sabe como podría imprimir una hoja como esta pero con SQL server. ya tengo las tablas en SQL server pero me pidieron que se vea exactamente así como está en la imagen, por favor si alguien sabe me harían un gran favor. gracias por su tiempo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me parece un poco confusa tu pregunta, pero aqui vamos... En la imagen se aprecia una hoja de calculo excel con una plantilla determinada, podrias EXPORTAR la información de las tablas a formato excel desde SQLSERVER, porque directamente desde el software desconozco que se pueda hacer. saludos

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Por otro lado, además de que la pregunta no encaja. NO ES POSIBLE. Sql server no es una hoja de cálculo. No puedes ver la imagen, por ejemplo. Por supuesto que puede devolver los datos a las aplicaciones que los consuman, pero eso así no se puede hacer

Comment: de csualidad has intentado usar [tag:ssrs]?

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que hacer una consulta de este tipo y luego con tu programa hacer que se genere el excel con estos datos, o simplemente en sqlServer en los datos, boton derecho y guardar como csv.

```
select campo1 as 'Nº', campo2 as Apellidos,
campo3 as Nombres, campo4 as 'C.I', campo5 as Expedicion,
campo6 as Folio, campo7 as Matricula from tabla 
inner join tablas on tablas.....
```

Comment: Hola , Gracias por la idea y por responder . Lo probaré